# Error from Entity Framework: Unable to update database to match the current model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm new to Entity Framework in general, and just starting to work toward implementing migrations.

When I first set up my model classes and corresponding `DbContext` class, the class got an override of `OnModelCreating`, into which I put FluentAPI commands to set things like `IsMaxLength` and `HasPrecision`.

I have since created an InitialCreate migration that was given the name "201708081210041_InitialCreate".

Database (re)creation was not an issue before, but it is now.  If I leave all of that in place, and allow EF to create the database, I get this error message:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are
>   pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the
>   pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic
>   migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to
>   true to enable automatic migration.

While I have found references to this message in other Q&A, I don't understand it all well enough to make sense of the underlying problem that I have caused.

Some additional bits of information:

1. If I comment out the code in `OnModelCreating` the error stops.
2. No changes have been made to the model classes since `InitialCreate`
       was made.
3. The database initializer is being set to `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`.
4. `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false`

Are these things incompatible?  Am I supposed to "save" those changes myself, somehow?  Should I avoid `OnModelCreating` now that I have turned on migrations?

**UPDATE**:
I was able to resolve this particular issue by eliminating the `OnModelCreating` code altogether.  To do so, I added all of its actions to the `InitialCreate` code.  I also learned that the previous model is stored in the `resx` of the migration (which you can only see by examining the XML directly, btw), which was also injecting some changes.  Apparently, there was a slight difference between that previous iteration, the `OnModelCreating` code, and the actual migration.  The whole thing seems *very* fragile to me.

Comment: Most likely some of the fluent configuration changes you've made inside `OnModelCreating` are incompatible with the previous db model, hence EF requires migration (to keep db and code models in sync). Just generate another migration (via PM `add-migration`) or enable the automatic migrations.

Comment: @IvanStoev The migration I cited was just created today.  And the Fluent commands predate that even.  Since nothing has changed since then, why would it be different?

Comment: If you want to be sure there are no future changes, you could always do `add-migration` - if it's empty, you can simply delete the generated `cs` file. So restore the `OnModelCreating` code, do `add-migration` and see if there is something in the migration.

Comment: @IvanStoev Interesting.  The resulting migration has one index being removed and re-added, and a long list of `AlterColumn` calls, which looks to be the exact thing that `OnModelCreating` is attempting to do.  I don't understand this at all.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Without seeing your `OnModelCreating` and the migrations, it's impossible to say *exactly* what happened, but if your code in `OnModelCreating` creates a different DB schema than the original, it's quite obvious that it would need to have a new migration to update the database to the new changes.